# How to assign existing function to object (not call it immediately) by it's name as a String from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I would like some help assigning function to object. I have JSON file containing function names *(as string ofc...)* and in my code I have already existing functions. I **don't** want this functions to be **called just assigned** so I can call them later.

I also want to be able to pass a custom function as a string from JSON file. I tried to parse it but I get ***Unexpected token m...***

**operations.push --> run:** is where I want to assign function.

This is my code with what I have tried so far:

```
async function operate(schemaObject) {
    let operations = [];
    for (let operation in schemaObject.operate) {
        if(schemaObject.operate.hasOwnProperty(operation)) {

            //Function name as a string ex: "matchIntegerOrUnlimited"
            let functionName = schemaObject.operate[operation].action;

            //Function parameter (val) ex: "test 123"
            let functionParam = schemaObject.operate[operation].parameter;

            //Custom Function ex: "return alert(Hello)
            if (operation.custom) { 
                operations.push({
                    run: new Function("test 123", return alert("123"),
                    on: schemaObject.operate[operation].key
                });
            } else {
             //Push existing Function matchIntegerOrUnlimited()
                operations.push({
                    run: functionName, //"matchIntegerOrUnlimited"
                    on: schemaObject.operate[operation].key
                });
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(operations);
    return operations;
}
function matchIntegerOrUnlimited(val) {
    if (contains(val, unlimitedPattern)) {
        return 10000;
    } else {
        let number = val.match(numberPattern)[0];
        return parseInt(number, 10);
    }
}
```

So I expect to be able to just assign function that can be called later by giving a existing function name as Sting... and also if possible to give a custom function as a **String**

Comment: have you tried using `eval()` ?

Comment: *"I also want to be able to pass a custom function as a string from JSON file."* You're using `new Function` on `functionParam`, not `functionName`, but your comments suggest that `functionParam` is a parameter, not a function (and the other name suggests it's **name**, not function source text as a string). We can't help you without a much clearer description, including what the strings look like, ideally without all the `operation` chaff. Please see: [mcve]

Comment: As you said those functions exist. If they exist in the global scope so you can save the function name as string and later call it by `window[operations[n].run]()` (or replace window with global...). You can also assign a reference to the existing function `run: window[functionName]` and later call it by `operations[n].run()`.